# Orthogonal matrices 5

Tags: matrices

The question is to find in the space $\mathrm{Mat}_{3\times 2}(\mathbb{\mathbb{R}})$ a non-zero matrix that is orthogonal to
$$ A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\\      
3 & 4\\      
5 & 6\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

The inner product is $\langle A, B \rangle = tr(A B^T) = tr(B^T A)$.

Any hints or clues on how to start this?

Comment: Please format your comment, it's not clear what space you're referring to. Is it $\mathbb{R}^{32}$? Also, what does it mean to ask for a "matrix" that is orhogonal to some other matrix? Do you mean to say orthogonal vector?

Comment: I suppose he means $Mat_{3,2}(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. the space of $3\times 2$ matrices. That said, I have no clue to which orthogonality he is referring to

Comment: What is your inner product? $\langle A, B \rangle = tr(A B^T)$?

Comment: Yes Batman that is the inner product. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You want to find a matrix $B$ such that $\langle A,B \rangle = tr(A B^T) = tr(B^T A) =0$ (recall $tr(AB) = tr(BA)$ by invariance of trace under cyclic permutations)

Let $B = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \\ e & f \end{bmatrix}$, and calculate $\langle A,B \rangle = tr(A B^T) = tr(B^T A ) = tr\left(\begin{bmatrix} a & c & e \\ b & d & f \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \\ 5 & 6 \end{bmatrix} \right) = a+3c+5e+2b+4d+6f$.

Now, simply pick a set of 6 numbers $a,b,c,d,e,f$ such that $a+3c+5e+2b+4d+6f=0$ and this specifies the matrix $B$. You can do this by picking $a,b,c,d,e$ arbitrarily (but at least one must be non-zero) and then solving for the required value of $f$ to make this equality true. For example, you can pick $a=1,b=c=d=e=0$ and this would require $f = -1/6$ to give such a matrix.